# How to render Shiny line plot from renderDataTable?

Tags: r, web-scraping, shiny, rvest, line-plot

I web-scrapped html table data from webpage and produced a Shiny Data Table. But I have no idea in outputting a Shiny line plot. The table is shown below:

[image]

Here are my questions:

1. How should I call the table? `df` or `df()`? What is the difference?
2. Is date is the correct name of x variable in `aes (x =  )`?
3. If I want to display the lines of 'arr_Hong Kong Residents', 'arr_Mainland Visitors', 'arr_Other Vistors', 'dep_Hong Kong Residents', 'dep_Mainland Visitors', 'dep_Other Vistors', how should I call `aes (y = )` without hard-coding the label names?

Below is my code.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    "daterange",
    "Date range:",
    start  = "2022-10-19",
    end    = Sys.Date() - 1,
    min    = "2022-10-01",
    max    = Sys.Date() - 1,
    format = "yyyymmdd",
    separator = "/"
  ),
  textOutput("ShowUrl"),
  hr(),
  textOutput("ShowHtml"),
  dataTableOutput("T"),
  plotOutput("L")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  prefixes <- c("arr", "dep")
  
  cols <-
    c("Hong Kong Residents",
      "Mainland Visitors",
      "Other Visitors",
      "Total")
  headers <-
    c(
      "Control_Point",
      crossing(prefixes, cols) %>% unite("headers", 1:2, remove = T) %>% unlist() %>% unname()
    )
  
  
  output$T <- renderDataTable({
    
    date_seq<- seq(input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2], by = "1 day")
    
    rows <- map(date_seq, ~ {
      URL <- 
        paste0("https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/stat_", format(., "%Y%m%d"),
               ".html")
      message(URL)
      rows <-
        read_html(URL) %>% html_elements(".table-passengerTrafficStat tbody tr.a")})
    
    df <- map_dfr(rows,
                  function(x) {
                    x %>%
                      html_elements("td[headers]") %>%
                      set_names(headers[seq_len(NROW(.))]) %>%
                      html_text()
                  }) %>%
      mutate(across(c(-1), ~ str_replace(.x, ",", "") %>% as.integer())) %>%
      mutate(date =  date_seq)
    
    df
  })
  
  output$L <- renderPlot({ggplot(df(), aes(x = date, y = prop))  + geom_line(size = 2)
  })  #THIS IS MY PUZZLE
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thank you for solving the problem in advance.

Comment: I think the appropriate way to handle this is to create a dataframe from what you read in and then use that dataframe in `renderDataTable()` and `renderPlot()`. If you need the dataframe to be dynamic (meaning it can be updated or changed or subset in some way, then make it a reactive object and pass that object into each rendering function

Answer (score 0):

Try this (may require tweaks)
date_seq<- seq(input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2], by = "1 day")

```
    rows <- map(date_seq, ~ {
      URL <- 
        paste0("https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/stat_", format(., "%Y%m%d"),
               ".html")
      message(URL)
      rows <-
        read_html(URL) %>% html_elements(".table-passengerTrafficStat tbody tr.a")})
    
    df <- map_dfr(rows,
                  function(x) {
                    x %>%
                      html_elements("td[headers]") %>%
                      set_names(headers[seq_len(NROW(.))]) %>%
                      html_text()
                  }) %>%
      mutate(across(c(-1), ~ str_replace(.x, ",", "") %>% as.integer())) %>%
      mutate(date =  date_seq)
    
   
output$T <- renderDataTable({df})
  
  output$L <- renderPlot({ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = prop))  + geom_line(size = 2)
  })  #THIS IS MY PUZZLE
}
```

but I think making it reactive would be better because it takes input!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I actually produced a dataframe beforehand, but I don't know how to modify it into shiny reactive. Wonder if you can give a helping hand.,

Comment: The code is here (1 of 2):

start <- as.Date("21-09-22", format = "%d-%m-%y")
end   <- as.Date("01-10-22", format = "%d-%m-%y")
 
prefixes <- c("arr", "dep")
cols <-
   c("Hong Kong Residents",
     "Mainland Visitors",
     "Other Visitors",
     "Total")
headers <-
   c("Control_Point", crossing(prefixes, cols) %>% unite("headers", 1:2, remove = T) %>% unlist() %>% unname())
 
answer <- list() 
theDate <- start

Comment: code 2 of 2:

while (theDate <= end) {
   url_data <-
      print(paste0("https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/stat_", format(theDate, "%Y%m%d"), ".html"
      )) 
  rows <-
      read_html(url_data) %>% html_elements(".table-passengerTrafficStat tbody tr.a")
       df <- map_dfr(rows,
          function(x) {
              x %>%
                 html_elements("td[headers]") %>%
                    set_names(headers) %>%
                       html_text()
                 })  %>%
    mutate(date = theDate)         
   answer[[theDate]] <-df
   theDate <- theDate + 1
}

@sconfluentus